# How to store identical html blocks in a project correctly? I want to use the same block in different views

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a block that opens modally for selection from a list. I don't want to embed it in every view. I want this to happen through Razor or C#. I think it would be wrong to store this in _Layout.cshtml (I could be wrong).

```html
<label hidden id="selectionInitiator"></label>
<label hidden id="sourceList"></label>
<div id="modalDialog" class="modal fade">
    <div id="dialogContent" class="modal-dialog">
        <div style="background:white; padding:15px; border-radius:5px;">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal" area-hidden="true">X</button>
                <h4>Выберите элемент из списка</h4>
            </div>
            <div id="modalContainer" class="modal-body">
                <div class="treeItems" id="treeRoot">
                    <!-- Dymanical -->
                    Загрузка данных...

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why you think it would be wrong to store this in _Layout.cshtml?If you store it in layout,it will be shown in each view which layout is _Layout.cshtml.

Answer (score 1):

This type of reusable code for modal boxes should be in the `_Layout.cshtml` file. Otherwise you will have to remember and add in all the pages where you need the modal box.

However if you do not want to put the html in the `_Layout.cshtml` file then you have to include it in all the views where you need those. For that you can do the followings:

- Move the html to a partial view, call it `_ModalBox.cshtml`
- Include the partial view in all the pages where you need that
- Use javascript to hide/show the modal (I guess you are already doing that)

First Move the view to a partial file called `_ModalBox.cshtml`. Keep this file in the `Shared` folder.

Then include the view in the pages like this:

```
@await Html.PartialAsync("_ModalBox.cshtml")
```

Note: You can add the `_ModalBox.cshtml` partial view to the `_Layout.cshtml` file instead. That would be the better practice.